# Chart.js: Can datasets be overlaid in a bar chart? (Not the same as stacked)

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I'd like to display a "total amount" and a "filtered amount" on a bar chart. A stacked bar chart doesn't quite work because it shows both amounts in full on top of one another; in this case I'd like it to appear as though the bar has been "filtered", so the "remaining/filtered" amount is greyed out. amCharts lets you do this by setting `clustered: false`. Is it possible in Chart.js?

Here's an example of the functionality I'm trying to build -- the bar chart on the right is the desired appearance (using amCharts).

[image: screenshot of desired functionality]

Answer (score 0):

You can set `stacked: true` inside `xAxes` and leave `yAxes` alone to get this effect.

Comment: I just tried this and now my bars are next to each other.